# Disable text input history

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)

I am building an application which will be accepting credit card data. I would like to make sure that the browser does *not* remember what has been typed into the text inputs for credit card number. I tried passing the following headers:

```
header("Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

Still, once the page reloads, I can click the credit card text input field and it will let me see what I wrote in it before. How can I prevent this?

Comment: This is not a server-side issue, it's the browser's autocomplete functionality at work.

Comment: I was also considering that this might be the case, but I made a little test: I went on PayPal to reset my password. Resetting the password involves entering the credit card number assigned to my account. I did this twice - the reset password page does NOT remember what I entered the first time in the credit card number field.

Comment: Is there a conclusion you can reach from that test?

Comment: I couldn't, that's what led me to asking the question here :)

Answer (score 212, accepted):

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off"/>
```

Should work. Alternatively, use:

```
<form autocomplete="off" … >
```

for the entire form (see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)).

Comment: That's not a related question, that's an exact duplicate.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: An exact duplicate is by property a related question and the reciprocal is false.

Answer (score 14):

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: But it is non-standard(?). Does it work in 2020?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Hi from 2022: It almost never works and browsers behave very differently (chrome being the one that ignores this the most)